# expected cache-effect when summing arrays is missing

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, caching, cpu-cache

I expect the following program to be completely memory-bound in terms of performance (the arrays are way bigger than the L3-cache).

Therefor I expected the sum of the long array to take almost twice as much time as the sum of the int array.

But they take both almost the same time:

```
 int sum took 81 ms, result = 4999999950000000
long sum took 87 ms, result = 4999999950000000
```

Can anybody explain this?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace MemoryPerformance
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int count = 100_000_000;
            int[] intArray = Enumerable.Range(0, count).ToArray();
            long[] longArray = intArray.Select(x => (long)x).ToArray();
            Measure(() => intSum(intArray), " int sum");
            Measure(() => longSum(longArray), "long sum");
        }

        static long intSum(int[] array)
        {
            long sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) sum += array[i];
            return sum;
        }

        static long longSum(long[] array)
        {
            long sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) sum += array[i];
            return sum;
        }

        static void Measure(Func<long> calc, string description)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            long sum = calc();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"{description} took {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms, result = {sum}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are never using the sum, it could be that the compiler completely optimizes away your loop. Just a guess, though. Try outputting the result to make sure this is not the case.

Comment: I modified the code -- same result.

Comment: Loop unrolling and prefetching maybe? So in the end the result is almost completely "CPU-bound" and memory effects are hidden by prefetching? That would mean 80ms is the time it takes to calculate the sums. Did you check how long it takes *without* the arrays?

Comment: Do you realize that you're converting all of your `int`s to `long`s with each array access?

Comment: @Sebastian: I guess this was the right hint: Summing only (without array) takes abount 60ms (75% running time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run this several times I get about the same results, but worse: (printing of the result added just in case)

```
 int sum took 84 ms (4999999950000000)
long sum took 77 ms (4999999950000000)
 int sum took 84 ms (4999999950000000)
long sum took 76 ms (4999999950000000)
 int sum took 84 ms (4999999950000000)
long sum took 77 ms (4999999950000000)
 int sum took 83 ms (4999999950000000)
long sum took 76 ms (4999999950000000)
```

So with longs it's *faster*? One this that it is *not* doing that the `int` version is, is sign extension. It could be that. Actually I don't know what else it could be.

But this is just what happens when all elements of the array are added. If I take only every 8th element (8th because cache lines are 64 bytes and longs are 8, so 8 fit in a cache line), this happens:

```
 int sum took 25 ms (624999950000000)
long sum took 49 ms (624999950000000)
 int sum took 23 ms (624999950000000)
long sum took 49 ms (624999950000000)
 int sum took 23 ms (624999950000000)
long sum took 48 ms (624999950000000)
 int sum took 23 ms (624999950000000)
long sum took 48 ms (624999950000000)
```

This is very different, with indeed the `int` version being about twice as fast as the `long` version, corresponding with the number of cache misses expected for both versions.

So I may conclude from this that in the "full" version apparently enough arithmetic (or at least "stuff that isn't the memory access", including loop overhead) happens to hide most of the cache miss penalty, combined with actually doing less work in the `long` version.

Also I think we should keep in mind that since this is a completely linear access pattern, it should be expected that hardware prefetching does a good job. The throughput of automatic prefetching may or may not be adequate, but it shouldn't be that bad of a case - it is not unreasonable that doing a bit of computation allows prefetching to "catch up".

---

Relevant code that uses only every 8th element:

```
    static long intSum(int[] array)
    {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 8) sum += array[i];
        return sum;
    }

    static long longSum(long[] array)
    {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 8) sum += array[i];
        return sum;
    }
```

Timing on [ideone](https://ideone.com/wfy8du)

Comment: I came to the same conclusion: I believe the time is all just "CPU" time and memory access is completely ignored because of prefetching and maybe loop unrolling. See [my fork](https://ideone.com/GwpmrE) - it's almost completely "CPU-bound" and takes almost as much time if no memory is accessed at all. With every 8th element the access is "too random" and we get 8 times more cache misses/waits for the out of order fetch to return.

Answer (score 3):

The time you are measuring is mainly "just the CPU time".
If you only sum up the numbers and omit the whole memory access like in [this fork of Harolds answer](https://ideone.com/GwpmrE), you will see that it takes almost the same amount of time to simply add up all the numbers in a loop, *without* reading them from the array/memory:

```
static long noSum(long[] array)
{
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i ++) sum += i;
        return sum;
}
```

This means that even though the CPU *has* to fetch the data from the memory and cannot keep it all in the cache, it can do this very efficiently because you are not using random array access: In the case of your loops it has plenty of time to prefetch the next cache line while it is still performing the computations. This results in almost no waiting time (speculative execution anyone?! ;-) ). Hence it doesn't matter *in your case*. It does in those cases where you need to access a lot of memory more quickly like in Harolds "sparse" test-case, obviously.